# como ocultar la barra de estado cuando pongo el cursor sobre un link

Tags: html, iframe

es la primera vez que publico algo aqui en esta pagina, he buscado muchas soluciones sobre html y la verdad me ha ayudado mucho, tengo una pregunta, no logro obtener la respuesta aun.

> ¿Como hago para ocultar la barra de estado o cambiar el nombre de ella cuando el cursor se pone encima?

Tengo un `iframe` normal, abajo de el pongo las opciones de ese `iframe`;

actualizar opcion, opcion 2 y opcion 3, **el problema es que cuando se pone el cursor sobre opcion 2 o 3 sale el link del stream, y no quiero que eso aparezca**, cabe recalcar que las opciones deben cargar en el mismo iframe, tengo colocado el `href="javascript:document.location.reload();` y las tres me cargan en el mismo `iframe` sin problema e incluso mas si quiero agregar, pero no puedo ocultar o cambiar el link que aparece, adjunto dos imagenes, una de como me sale y otro ejemplo de otra pagina como me gustaria que saliera.

Comparto los ejemplos y el iframe que tengo

Asi me sale a mi, se ve el link.
[image: AQUI ES EL EJEMPLO 1 DE COMO ME SALE A MI]

y asi quiero que me salga, este ejemplo es de otra pagina, donde no se ve el link de lo que se va a repruducir, solo se ve otro link que lo ponen por encima o algo asi.
[image: AQUI EL EJEMPLO 2 DE OTRA PAGINA PERO COMO ME GUSTARIA QUE SALIERA,]

Les comparto el iframe que tengo no si esta desordenado solo que se funciona, no se mucho sobre codigo pero me defiendo en algo jajaja, espero obtener respuesta, muchas gracias.

````
    <center>    
<div class="player"><iframe allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="500" name="streamframe" scrolling="no" src="https://1rowsports.com/player/1/120" width="700"></iframe></div>                                                                                                                                                      
<div id="sse50">
  <div id="sses50">   
  <span>OPCIONES</span> <a href="javascript:document.location.reload();" id=""><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"> </span> ACTUALIZAR OPCION 1</a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://1rowsports.com/player/1/120" rel="nofollow" target="streamframe">OPCION 2</a>&nbsp;<a class="btn btn-primary" href="https://1rowsports.com/player/1/120" rel="nofollow" style="text-align: left;" target="streamframe">OPCION 3</a></div></div>    
  <center></center></center>
<!--REPRODUCTOR--> ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto

```html
<div class="player">
    <iframe id="streamframe" allow="encrypted-media" allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="500" name="streamframe" scrolling="no" src="https://1rowsports.com/player/1/120" width="700"></iframe>
    </div>                                                                                                                                                      
<div id="sse50">
  <div id="sses50">   
      <span>OPCIONES</span> 
      <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('streamframe').src = document.getElementById('streamframe').src"  id="document"><span class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin"> </span> ACTUALIZAR OPCION 1</a>
      <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('streamframe').src = 'https://1rowsports.com/player/1/120'">OPCION 2</a>&nbsp;
      <a class="btn btn-primary" onclick="document.getElementById('streamframe').src = 'https://1rowsports.com/player/1/121'" style="text-align: left;" >OPCION 3</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola, si me funciono pero ya no aparece el estilo de los botones, pero el link ya no aparece, como podria arreglar el estilo de los botones, ya que con ese codigo no aparece, gracias :)